# Assembly infinite loop

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

My saga with x86 assembly continues, I'm getting into an infinite loop with this piece of code and I'm a bit puzzled.

```
movl $1, %ecx
movl $4, %edi

do_loop:
   cmpl %edi, %ecx
   je do_exit
   .........
   do_stuff
   .........
   incl %ecx
   jmp do_loop
do_exit:
```

I'm expecting a jump to **do_exit:** when %ecx reaches 4 since it's incremented in every iteration

Comment: Something tells me you're reusing/reassigning ecx in your do_stuff section...

Comment: do_stuff makes some calls to printf, apparently it modifies the registers. I didn't expect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, be careful with register usage in `do_stuff`. And the real thing that you are looking for are [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl), and especially this line:

*Registers EAX, ECX, and EDX are available for use in the function.*

Answer (score 1):

No debugger? Does do_stuff modify %edi? Try commenting do_stuff out.

Comment: i'm just making a call to printf. savind ecx and edi on the stack before the call and poping them up after seems to give a correct result. weird I didn't expect this.

Comment: @void: The calling convention allows for `ecx` to be modified by a called function, along with `eax` and `edx`. The rest must be preserved. Thus, you don't have to save `edi` across the call to `printf`.
Note, this applies to your function too.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if the do_exit is followed by blanks and I have no idea how you are executing the assembly code...

but try to add the following after the do_exit:

> leave
>
> ret